# How to convert a pandas data frame to a sliceable dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame `df` that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 'Jack', 'A'], [1, 'Jamie', 'A'], [1, 'Mo', 'B'], [1, 'Tammy', 'A'], [2, 'JJ', 'A'], [2, 'Perry', 'C']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'name', 'class'])
> df
   id   name class
0   1   Jack     A
1   1  Jamie     A
2   1     Mo     B
3   1  Tammy     A
4   2     JJ     A
5   2  Perry     C
```

I want to convert this to a dictionary `mydict` where

```
> mydict[0]
{'id': '1', 'name': ['Jack', 'Jamie', 'Mo', 'Tammy'], 'class': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A']}

> mydict[1]
{'id': '2', 'name': ['JJ', 'Perry'], 'class': ['A', 'C']}
```

and

```
> mydict[0:2]
{'id': ['1', '2'], 'name': [['Jack', 'Jamie', 'Mo', 'Tammy'],['JJ', 'Perry']], 'class': [['A', 'A', 'B', 'A'], ['A', 'C']]}
```

I tried `mydict = df.to_dict()` but that didn't seem to work as intended.

Comment: I did look at that and tried its top answer, but it didn't work as intended.

Comment: The linked duplicated doesn't really solve this issue

Comment: There is no such thing as a sliceable dictionary. It's definitely possible to create a custom mapping that can do this or perhaps even construct a Pandas object that can. But I guess either is relatively complicated.
https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping

Comment: @Adrian I retracted my close vote and voted to reopen the question. Which I leave my apology here with you. I hope it gets open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
mydict = df.groupby('id').agg(list).reset_index().T.to_dict()
```

**Output**

`mydict[0]`

```
{'id': 1, 'name': ['Jack', 'Jamie', 'Mo', 'Tammy'], 'class': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
```

---

`mydict`

```
{0: {'id': 1, 'name': ['Jack', 'Jamie', 'Mo', 'Tammy'], 'class': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A']},
 1: {'id': 2, 'name': ['JJ', 'Perry'], 'class': ['A', 'C']}}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to create `mydict` so that it's sliceable? Please see my edited post, i.e., the output for `mydict[0:2]`

Comment: You can use basic python to convert value of a dictionary into list.

Comment: @PandaKim but slicing in Pandas is open (including the 2) while list-slicing in Python is only half-open (excluding the 2).

Comment: @Joooeey could you elaborate this a bit? You meant `itertools` slicing can be applied to dictionaries but not for list (limited)?

Comment: Slicing in Pandas is complex. See link. In this particular case, it seems the OP wants to refer to the ids 0, 1, 2 with `0:2`. This only works when using label-based indexing in Pandas. In pure Python `0:2` only refers to 0 and 1. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
out = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(list).to_dict('records')
```

Alternative:

```
out = [{'id': k} | g.drop(columns='id').to_dict('list')
       for k, g in df.groupby('id', as_index=False)]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1,
  'name': ['Jack', 'Jamie', 'Mo', 'Tammy'],
  'class': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A']},
 {'id': 2, 'name': ['JJ', 'Perry'], 'class': ['A', 'C']}]
```

Alternative, as dictionary:

```
out = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(list).to_dict('index')
```

Output:

```
{0: {'id': 1,
     'name': ['Jack', 'Jamie', 'Mo', 'Tammy'],
     'class': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A']},
 1: {'id': 2, 'name': ['JJ', 'Perry'], 'class': ['A', 'C']}}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `ValueError: orient 'record' not understood`. Any advice?

Comment: which pandas version do you have?

Comment: Pandas version 2.0.0

Comment: @Adrian my bad, if forgot the `s` in `records`, versions prior to 2.0.0 would accept shortcuts

Comment: No worries, all good. Is it possible to get it to be in the format shown in the original post with `mydict[0:2]`?

Comment: No, it's impossible, you can't slice a dictionary. Only index it.

Comment: @mozway and Adrian, is this not [the slicing](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/python-slice-dictionary/) that you are referring to? It uses `import itertools`